# MySQL Connection refused only with PHP, Javascript is working on my server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, digital-ocean

Something very strange is happening, I have 2 applications running on 1 Digital Ocean server, application A developed in PHP connects to external MySQL Y, application B made in JS connects to that same database Y. In the app in PHP I get a refused connection error and JS lists the data that comes from MySql. What can cause this error only in PHP? Since my connection variables are correct, the server is in the whitelist of the database service. I also uploaded a conexao.php file to the server and also gave connection refused.

Comment: What operating system is the server running? If it is Red Hat Linux or CentOS or their derivatives and is running selinux, there is a security parameter configured off by default for some web servers. Check `getenforce` - if `Enforcing`, then SELinux is running and you might need to modify a bool like `httpd_can_network_connect_db`. This is a shot in the dark, knowing little about your setup, but definitely something I have encountered many times.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I use Ubuntu 18, I checked here and SELinux is showing disabled.

Comment: Ok on Ubuntu, is AppArmor running?  I have less experience but I believe it is capable of meddling with database connections as SELinux does

Comment: Yes, he's running

Comment: I don't know specifically how to check for db connectivity blocks in apparmor, but test if the connection works when you disable apparmor entirely

Comment: I'd assume that a different hostname is used for the authentication ...check the users table on MySQL itself and make sure the user has the proper host added, in order to connect. MySQLd is a network service and it should not care what connects it, while the credentials match. I'd rather wonder what you mean by "whitelist of the database service"? Please add code & output of `conexao.php`, to begin with.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the hostname is the same, because the application works on my localhost authenticating with the external DB.